# Set up default JVM Args for JDK 1.7 for TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

Whenever i try to run a TestNg test via eclipse, it gives me the following error:
**VM version 1.6.0 is invalid, Java 1.7 or above is required for running TestNG.**

[image]

[image]

I have tried setting it from preferences, but not sure how can i set up Java version as part of JVM args at preferences:

[image]

Comment: Check your java version on terminal, TestNG you have downloaded needs
Java 7

Comment: java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: surprising, your eclipse is picking Java 6,
two things you can try first- check which java you are using for your project and second - remove java 6 which comes by default on Macintosh

Comment: How can i check Jaba for my project ?

Comment: Also i think i miay be able to fix up if i use JVM arguments to use JDK1.7, i havea path for that as well

Comment: http://imgur.com/dkB5VpX

Comment: Look at 'Java > Installed JREs' in the Preferences to see which JRE/JDKs your Eclipse knows about. Look in 'Run > Run Configurations...' to see what JRE the Launch is using.